# If I change my app to free, how could I tell who has paid before? Is the old license checking method still working?

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to change my app to a free one.

Instead of charging directly. I want to use the "In-paid app" method.

However, I have to find a way to keep the rights of the old paid users (who don't use the In-paid app method).

```
How could I tell who are the old paid users and who are the new free users?
Is the old license checking method still working?
```

If I can't use the old license checking method, please provide the possible solution.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#app-publishing) it will be impossible for the old users to update their app to the new free one because of the mandatory package name change. Also, licensing is only available to paid apps atm. You are not allowed to include the licensing permission in free apps.

You may have to deal with it manually. Like upgrading your paid app and including a method informing them and allowing them sending licensed user's data to you so you can refund them on the new app's in-app purchase.